# How to return multiple objects as JSON from asp.net webservice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, web-services

I have the following code to return a one-object JSON array,

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<ServiceContract(Namespace:="")> _
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)> _
Public Class MessageService
    <OperationContract()> _
    Public Function GetMessage(Id As Integer) As String
        Dim m As New NewMessage()
        m.Id = 1
        m.Text = "Text test"

        Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
        Dim serializer As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(NewMessage))
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, m)

        serializer.WriteObject(stream, m)

        stream.Position = 0
        Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(stream)
        Return streamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Function
End Class


<DataContract()> _
Public Class NewMessage
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Id As Integer
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Text As String
End Class
```

The returned data is :

```
{id:1,Text:"TText test"}
```

How to make it returns :

```
[{id:1,Text:"Text 1"},{id:2,Text:"Text 2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you will have to return an array of your class NewMessage or if you want to return a single object, than make a class which has a property as array of NewMessage and return that class.

Answer (score 0):

to make it return

```
[{id:1,Text:"Text 1"},{id:2,Text:"Text 2"}]
```

you'll have to change NewMessage to List< NewMessage > instead. DataContractJsonSerializer will handle the rest.